# Using Class names as identifiers

Tags: java

If I did `String String = "String"` then I can use the methods in *variable* String. If I wanted to use the static methods in *class* String, how do I do that?

Comment: You'll have to provide examples, this question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a fully qualified name, for example, java.lang.String.length()

Comment: Er, that's not a static method.

Comment: This may have worked because the OP made a variable called String and it had a length of six ("String"), if the code provided by the OP was actually used (which it should not have been, since it has the same name as its variable type). Also, why would you ever need to use the fully qualified name of String, since it's already imported/included by Java.

Answer (score 2):

To use the static methods in String you can just call them like you were calling methods for other objects. Do `String.methodName(parameters)`. Also, don't give variables names that are already used (String is a used name). If you were referring to the String manipulation methods of String variables you would do `NameOfStringVariable.stringMethod(parameters)` to use those methods (the non-static ones).

Comment: There's a [public static String join(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence... elements)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) in Java 8 now.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to check for newer methods. It's been a while since I've seriously used Java.. But what I said still holds true, that method can be called like `String.join(...)`. Thanks for letting me know, I'll update it.